# Favicons and mixed content WHYYYY?

Tags: javascript, https, geolocation, favicon

I am building a web app that is served over https.  I am getting a lot of console warnings like these:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.sharewalks.com/' was loaded over 
HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 
'http://yandex.st/lego/_/pDu9OWAQKB0s2J9IojKpiS_Eho.ico?1493850556643'. 
This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

There are 14 of these - from the following urls (the numbers change):

FAVICON ERRORS:

- http://www.google.com/favicon.ico?1493850556625
- http://www.baidu.com/favicon.ico?1493850556625
- http://www.cloudflare.com/favicon.ico?1493850556625
- http://www.yandex.ru/favicon.ico?1493850556633

OTHER?:

- http://yandex.st/lego/_/pDu9OWAQKB0s2J9IojKpiS_Eho.ico?1493850556633

I need all content to be served HTTPS because I want to use geolocation services and I read that some browsers won't allow it unless ALL content is HTTPS.  In testing, navigator works on laptop Chrome, but not in mobile browsers (chrome, safari and firefox).

But I'm not requesting these favicons.  I don't really even know from where they are being called.

My question is what are these favicons and why are they messing with me?  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Do you have iframes that load pages from these other domains?

Comment: I am using google autocomplete in one place, and leaflet maps.  Would these be calling some of these?

Comment: It's possible. Make sure that when you load the `.js` and `.css` files, you use `https://` in the URLs.

Comment: Or just leave out the `http:` prefix entirely. It will then use the same protocol as was used to load your page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK I did a global search within my project for some of these url names, and lo! it turns out I was using a library called is-online which calls some of these sites as "tests" to see if you're online.  I changed the 'hostnames' file to use the full https url and voila the errors disappeared.  Thanks for Barmar for taking the time to answer me without merely downvoting my question!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, i see " Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mydomain.ir/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://www.mydomain.ir/wp-content/uploads/cropped-60-1-32x32.jpg'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. " , I can't find where it calling http.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox -> F12 -> console , you can see the errors of mixed content
Also in Chrome you have the same results in "developer tools" -> console

[image: developer tools]